# What am I doing wrong with this factorial program? It just keeps on returning back the original value

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    int num=5;
    int i=num-1;
    int factorial=0;

    while(i>0){

        factorial=num*i;
        i--;
     }
    System.out.println(""+factorial);
}
```

It just keeps on returning me 5. Sorry,if it sounds like a kiddish question, I am new to programming world.

Comment: Cole Pfeiffer, or T-Bag?

Comment: haha....I am in a prison coding on the walls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

**Replace**

`factorial=num*i;`

**with**

`num=num*i;`

**And**

`System.out.println(""+factorial);`

**with**

`System.out.println(""+num);`

**Reason**

You are running your `while` loop correctly. In each iteration, you are multiplying two successive numbers. But you are storing the result in `factorial` which gets overwritten with every iteration. So in the end, you end up getting the original number. So do as directed above, get rid of `factorial` varialble.

Comment: @ColePfeiffer, I added a reason in my answer to explain what's wrong with your approach. See if it makes sense.

Comment: @ColePfeiffer It works the first time, but after that, you are no longer multiplying by the previous value of num

Comment: @VHS Thanks u so much! You saved my mind from turning into a scrambled egg!

Answer (score 2):

I will not give you solution, but it is normal that it's storing 5, because your last execution is:

```
factorial = 5 * 1;
```

Now think twice what you HAVE to do.

Comment: Well i could not, i need 50 rep to reply a comment :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice, but I will help you get there ;)

Answer (score 1):

You Are Doing Something Wrong because it will execute as

```
    num is 5 and i is 4 // result will be 20
    then num is 5 and i is 3 // result will be 15
    then num is 5 and i is 2 // result will be 10
    then num is 5 and i is 1 // result will be 5
    while loop break
```

you need to store your previous result so use this

```
        int num=5;
        int factorial=1;

        while(num>0){

            factorial=num*factorial; // previous result will be store in factorial    
            num--;
         }
        System.out.println(""+factorial);
```

Now how this program is working

```
       num is 5 and fact is 1 // fact will be 5
        then num is 4 and fact is 5 // fact will be 20
        then num is 3 and fact is 20 // fact will be 60
        then num is 2 and fact is 60 // fact will be 120
        then num is 1 and fact is 120 // fact will be 120
        while loop break
```

Answer (score 0):

In each loop, you are multiplying the number by `i`, so in the end you will just get `num*1`. You can initialize the result variable `factorial` with the value of `num` and in each loop, assign it its value multiplied by `i`, that will result the multiplication of all numbers from 1 to `num` (factorial):

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    int num=5;
    int i=num-1;
    int factorial=num;

    while(i>0){

        factorial=factorial*i;
        i--;
    }

    System.out.println(""+factorial);
}
```